# ui-select2(multiple) with jquery 1.7.x not selecting values

Tags: jquery, angularjs

In my application I'm using jQuery 1.7(don't ask why :( ) with angularjs 1.2.5 and select2. I'm using [ui-select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2) for select2 integration with angularjs.

After updating to the latest version of ui-select2 the plugin stopped selecting values... The problem seems to the the `priority: 1` option added by the directive to add support for angularjs 1.2.x [this commit](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/commit/6b20bd783a4f7cf5f87c01f9ffb34635477ce425).

Demo: [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Msq2jn0pMbj2z89727gt?p=preview)

Has anybody faced this problem?

Script

```
var app = angular.module('my-app', ['ui.select2'], function () {

})

app.controller('AppController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.transition = {};

    var results = [{
        id: '1',
        text: 'One',
        type: 1
    }, {
        id: '2',
        text: 'Two',
        type: 1
    }, {
        id: '3',
        text: 'Three',
        type: 1
    }, {
        id: '4',
        text: 'Fout',
        type: 1
    }]
  $scope.select2Options = {
        id: 'id',
            data: results,
            multiple: true
  }
})
```

HTML:

```
  <body ng-controller="AppController">
    <input class="trans-values" ui-select2="select2Options" ng-model="transition.value" style="width: 150px" multiple />
  </body>
```

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward the property was added as a fix to another problem... so removing it won't be a wise choice.. upgrading jquery is not a choice for now... but still it throws an error in your console like `annot use 'in' operator to search for '0' in 2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Was little too silly from me to not look at the issues list in github. Issues [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2/issues/121) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5219)

I solved it by changing the target element from `input` to `div`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not up to date. See [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2).

```
<div ui-select2="select2Options" ng-model="list_of_string"></div>
```